# Granite stained by Liquid Nails

Tags: adhesive, granite, stain-removal

**Obligatory apology:** I am only an ambitious DIY'er and feel I can learn to do almost anything on my own, but that only works if I ask the right questions. Apparently I missed one. So yes, I am a doof.

**The mistake:** While installing a new granite vanity top and backsplash, the directions said "do not use plumber's putty". It seems it should say "do not use oil-based adhesives" though I guess that is a moot point.

I had Liquid Nails LN-715 Tub Surround, which is vinyl acrylic base, and used a thin bead on the top of the cabinet, which did not bleed through. But I used more on the back of the back and side splash, and now a day later there are dark spots showing.

I have scanned internet discussions, and see many people giving advice and not many OPs coming back to report what worked or what didn't. A lot of the advice is conflicting.

**The questions:** Since this adhesive is not oil based, can I expect that these spots are capable of drying and disappearing on their own? If not, what can I do to remove or blend the stains? Condensation from my cup left a ring (which dried quickly), so I am sure it is unsealed.

I have granite cleaner and granite sealer, but am hesitant to apply anything until I know how to deal with the stains.

**Options I am considering:** I see someone online had success blending his spots using a "natural based stain" but he gave no details on what he actually used.

Another said to use a heater or blow dryer.

Another said to apply a poultice. (Acetone? I think that was for regular LN)

Another said I am screwed. (Probably also regular LN)

I expect the sealer would hinder any drying, and might equally darken the spots as much as the other parts leaving the spots still visible. Maybe not... looking for experienced advice on that.

Thankfully, it is just the splashes, so replacing them is an option, though I would like it to be a last resort because I really don't want to rip away the surface of the wall to remove them. That, and the delay in finishing the project.

Thanks for any pointers you can give.

Comment: That's a tough one. My first thought was the poultice approach, but with floor dry or similar. I wouldn't go to a solvent yet. Try bandaging a batch of plain clay floor dry against a small area overnight. See if that draws it out at all.